# Is there a getElementsByTagName() like function for javascript string variables?

Tags: javascript, string

I can use the getElementsByTagName() function to get a collection of elements from an element in a web page.

I would like to be able to use a similar function on the contents of a javascript string variable instead of the contents of a DOM element.

How do I do this?

EDIT

I can do this by creating an element on the fly.

```
var myElement = new Element('div');
myElement.innerHTML = "<strong>hello</strong><em>there</em><strong>hot stuff</strong>";
var emCollection = myElement.getElementsByTagName('em');
alert(emCollection.length); // This gives 1
```

But creating an element on the fly for the convenience of using the getElementsByTagName() function just doesn't seem right and doesn't work with  elements in Internet Explorer.

Comment: That is, you want to search for text in a string?

Comment: Yes. I just don't want to create a regex forest if an alternative function is available.

Answer (score 4):

Injecting the string into DOM, as you have shown, is the easiest, most reliable way to do this. If you operate on a string, you will have to take into account all the possible escaping scenarios that would make something that **looks** like a tag not actually **be** a tag.

For example, you could have

```
<button value="<em>"/>
<button value="</em>"/>
```

in your markup - if you treat it as a string, you may think you have an `<em>` tag in there, but in actuality, you only have two button tags.

By injecting into DOM via `innerHTML` you are taking advantage of the browser's built-in HTML parser, which is pretty darn fast. Doing the same via regular expression would be a pain, and browsers don't generally provide DOM like functionality for finding elements within strings.

One other thing you could try would be parsing the string as XML, but I suspect this would be more troublesome and slower than the DOM injection method.

Answer (score 4):

```
var domParser = new DOMParser();
var htmlString = "<strong>hello</strong><em>there</em><strong>hot stuff</strong>";
var docElement = domParser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html").documentElement;
var emCollection = docElement.getElementsByTagName("em");
for (var i = 0; i < emCollection.length; i++) {
    console.log(emCollection[i]);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but the context on how to return the resulting changes as a string is missing.

Comment: @Routhinator The extracted elements are printed out one by one in the console as an example. You can change that depending on your needs.

Comment: I think my point here was, in order for this to be good enough to be an accepted answer, you should elaborate on what you've added here and show the result. While the code in this answer is great, it fails to be an answer because it's _just_ code.

Answer (score 3):

```
function countTags(html, tagName) {
    var matches = html.match(new RegExp("<" + tagName + "[\\s>]", "ig"));
    return matches ? matches.length : 0;
}

alert(
    countTags(
        "<strong>hello</strong><em>there</em><strong>hot stuff</strong>",
        "em"
    )
); // 1
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML in a string is nothing special.  It's just text in a string.  It needs to be parsed into a tree for it to be useful.  This is why you need to create an element, then call `getElementsByTagName` on it, as you show in your example.