# Is There any way to do the same role that the method .load() in jquery does to get part of html page with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm learning Ajax now and I have a problem finding videos or articles that use just javascript to do things that jquery does.
To load apart from an HTML page and put it on the page, using jquery it is just like that :

```
   $(function () {
      $("#showData").load("pageName.html #whatIWant");
    });
```

And the Data in #whatIWant will be in element with #showData id.
I can't figure how to do the same thing with Vanilla Js
thanks for your participation.

NOTE :
If I use the method below, I get all the data from the other page and I want to control the response.

```
const getData = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      } else {
        reject(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    request.open("get", url, true);
    request.send();
  });
};

getData("test.html")
  .then((resolve) => {
    console.log(resolve);
  })
  .catch((reject) => {
    console.error(reject);
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent to $.load without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132510/equivalent-to-load-without-jquery)

Comment: There is a problem using the method in this question ( I answered this question also and point to this problem), using the answers in this question I get all the data on the other page from the start head tag to the end, but I want just an element, not all the data exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch an HTML document.

```js
function fetchElement(url, selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (!this.responseXML || !this.responseXML.querySelector) reject("No HTML Document found");
      else resolve(this.responseXML.querySelector(selector));
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const myElement = await fetchElement("pageName.html", "#whatIWant");
document.querySelector("#showData").innerHTML = "";
document.querySelector("#showData").appendChild(myElement);
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to fetch the web page, along with the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse it.

```js
async function fetchElement(url, selector) {
    const data = await fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
    const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
    return parsed.querySelector(selector);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work with me, but I don't understand the role of if statement "if (!this.responseXML || !this.responseXML.querySelector)"

Comment: I just added it in to reject the promise in case something goes wrong such as the response being empty or not rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that I found when seeking answers.

```
let dom = new DOMParser();

const getData = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      } else {
        reject(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    request.open("get", url, true);
    request.send();
  });
};

getData("test.html")
  .then((resolve) => {
    let pageHtml = dom.parseFromString(resolve, "text/html");
    let element = pageHtml.querySelector("whatIWant");
    console.log(element);
  })
  .catch((reject) => {
    console.error(reject);
  });
```

This Answers and the other one up are both works for me, I hope these answers help someone.